# How to debug `Error while processing function` in `vim` and `nvim`?

Tags: debugging, vim, neovim

### TL;DR

How to find where exactly `vim` or `nvim` error started (which file?) when I'm interested in fixing the actual issue and not just removing the bad plugin? Anything better than `strace` and guesswork to find the error origin?

### Issue

I often add a plugin to my `vim` or `nvim` config and end up getting errors on hooks (buffer open, close, write):

```
"test.py" [New] 0L, 0C written
Error detected while processing function 343[12]..272:
line    8:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: _exec
E116: Invalid arguments for function get(a:args, 'exec', a:1['_exec'])
E15: Invalid expression: get(a:args, 'exec', a:1['_exec'])
```

The problem is, I have no idea where those come from, only get some line number of unknown file and I know it's not my `vim`/`nvim` config file.

Comment: Is that the whole stack trace. Do you 343 files loaded by `:scriptnames`?

Comment: This isn't `stacktrace` output, it's all that `vim` prints when I try to open an empty `test.py` file. Will check `:scriptnames` asap but yeah, I load plugins via manager so it's possible it's that many files. Is that what it is - the number of opened files?

Comment: This is obfuscated to me. function 343[12]..272: I don't know what it means normally its the name of the function which is easily found. But it seems like a number. I know that sometimes vim uses the order the file was loaded as a unique identifier for script local functions but I still though the name came with it.

Comment: Just to satisfy mine and yours curiosity: I have total of 114 vim-scripts loaded (27 plugins). So it seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhere, you have a plugin that has defined a dictionary with `anonymous-functions` (check the help related to this tag).

For the curious ones, it's done this way:

```
let d = {}
function! d.whatever() abort
   throw "blah"
endfunction
```

When you execute this function, you'll get the kind of error you're currently observing. That's why I stopped working this way to prefer:

```
let d = {}
function s:whatever() abort
   throw "blah"
endfunction
let d.whatever = function('s:whatever') " a workaround is required for older versions of vim
" At least this way I'll get a `<SNR>42_whatever` in the exception throwpoint, and thus a scriptname.
```

That's the why. Now, back to your problem, AFAIK, the only things you'll be able to know are the two functions that have been called:

- in line 12 of `:function {343}`, *you*'ve called
- `:function {272}` which contains an error at line 8.

Thanks to these two commands (may be prefixed with `:verbose`, I don't remember exactly), you'll get the source code of the two functions, which you should be able to use in order to grep your plugins to know where it appears.

Comment: Hahahahhahahaha I knew about `:function` but I would _never_ guess `{343}` is a function name :D Thanks a bunch!